# How can I remove the .html extension WITHOUT .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is my site.
http://matiny.tk/Antihero.html
As you can see, the `.html` extension is just sitting at the end. `.htaccess` does not work for me. It causes the CSS to go missing, or the site to have a 500 internal error.

I'm using cPanel.

Here are the codes that aren't working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\ .html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 .html
```

This next one is only slightly different.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I got this one from someone on Youtube...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 .html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you cant as far as i know

Comment: With only `.html` files and no framework behind, you can't.

Comment: To clarify are you saying that you want that page to be accessible via just `http://matiny.tk/Antihero`? If so we'd probably need more info on what your server is, etc.

Comment: it is possible with .htaccess . Show us your (faulty) .htaccess, and maybe we can help you. show us the .htaccess that makes your CSS going missing

Comment: Why do you need to remove the extension?

Comment: The profile picture you chose is inappropriate for our site and I've changed it back to the default. Please use a more suitable image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one ugly work-around:

rename your file to `index.php` and put it inside a folder called `Antihero`.

But better is to use `.htaccess`. You say you cannot use it. Show us your `.htaccess` and we'll help you use it!

**edit** Try this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If you look at the site http://matiny.tk/Antihero/ 
You'll see the CSS has been assassinated.

Comment: @BigDaddyMat Please don't put a trailing slash after the url. (Stackoverflow is even hiding that trailing slash. You'll see it once you click on the link.) For the rest, all is looking ok here: http://matiny.tk/Antihero . CSS is working ok.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with my system, since I'm seeing an Internal Serve error.

Comment: @BigDaddyMat No! Just don't use a trailing slash as I said. It works here: **http://matiny.tk/Antihero** , but it gives an error here: **http://matiny.tk/Antihero/** (this last one has a trailing slash. but stackoverflow isn't showing it)

Comment: @BigDaddyMat if you are really not using a trailing slash, then consider clearing your browser cache/history

Comment: Okay, it was just a Firefox issue. It worked just fine on Chrome before I cleared the history. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting are what's called pretty URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Antihero$ ./Antihero.html
```

This way you can share your link as http://matiny.tk/Antihero and you're apache will preserve that url while underneath it's actually serving Antihero.html.

See here for some more information: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

**EDITED:**
Your last example works fine for me in my htaccess files. [Links to examples have been removed (no longer using .htaccess on the server)]. If it's still not working, could you verify that your htaccess support is enabled in apache?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```